# Plot implicit equations

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve

I need to draw some curves in Python3 (I am quite used to `matplotlib.pyplot`) but I have never drawn such things before and I would really appreciate some tips (especially tips how to code it in a "tidy" way) and help.

There is an example (let's use a heart!):

```
x^2+(5y/4-sqrt[|x|])^2=1
```

How can I code such a thing? Should I cut that formula into normal areas and then draw them?

Comment: if you can convert it into `y = f(x)` or `x = f(t), y = g(t)` then maybe you could draw it.

Comment: This question is more general than the one marked as duplicate. In example: there is no restriction here to use Matplotlib.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the equation you show you want to plot an implicit function, you should use contour considering `F = x^2` and `G = 1-(5y/4-sqrt[|x|])^2`, then `F-G = 0`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta = 0.025
xrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
yrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)

# F is one side of the equation, G is the other
F = X**2
G = 1- (5*Y/4 - np.sqrt(np.abs(X)))**2
plt.contour((F - G), [0])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]