# How to plot implicit equation in plotly?

Tags: python, plot, graph, plotly

I want the accepted answer in [plot implicit equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624616/plot-implicit-equations-in-python-3) to transform into Plotly. 
I tried a lot of code, one of them is below, but I don't understand the documentation of Contour in Plotly.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

delta = 0.025
xrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
yrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)
F = X**2
G = 1- (5*Y/4 - np.sqrt(np.abs(X)))**2

fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Contour(
        z=[[F - G, 0]]
    ))
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `z = F-G` is the function that will have the zeros that you want to turn into a curve and plot, so don't wrap it in all the braces.  Then you'll want to just plot the single contour at zero, so use `contours` to specific the exact contour that you're interested in.

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
delta = 0.025
xrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
yrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)
F = X**2
G = 1- (5*Y/4 - np.sqrt(np.abs(X)))**2

fig = go.Figure(data =
    go.Contour(
        z = F-G,
        x = xrange,
        y = yrange,
        contours_coloring='lines',
        line_width = 2,
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=0,
            size=2,
        ),
    ))
fig.show()
```

This is a nice trick to get a rough idea of what the curve might look like, but it's fairly crude and will only give you the result to an accuracy of `delta`.  If you want the actual zeros at any point, you're better off using a solver, like `scipy optimize` as is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2484602/102302).