# How to return pairs of (x,y) coordinates defining an implicit curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math

I have implemented this Heart curve (Wolfram Mathworld) via an implicit function script I found here [Plot implicit equations in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624616/plot-implicit-equations-in-python-3)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

delta = 0.025
xrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
yrange = np.arange(-2, 2, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xrange,yrange)

# F is one side of the equation, G is the other
F = X**2
G = 1- (Y - (np.abs(X))**(2/3))**2
plt.contour((F - G), [0])
plt.show()
```

How would I extract the resulting array of x,y pairs defining this curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could say this is "cheating" a bit, but a rough, concise recipe can be getting points in the mesh that roughly satisfy the condition and getting their coordinates as follows:

```py
# subset points that are very close to satifying the exact condition
# and get their indices
x_id, y_id = np.nonzero(abs(F-G) < 8e-3)
# get coordinates corresponding to the indices
plt.scatter(xrange[x_id], yrange[y_id])
```

`xrange[x_id]`, `yrange[y_id]` are the desired arrays of coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really a `matplotlib` user and there may be much, much better ways of doing what you ask - so please wait and see if someone comes up with a proper answer...

However, for the moment, you appear to be plotting the array `F-G`, so I saved that as a TIF (because it can store floats) using `PIL` like this:

```
from PIL import Image

...
your code
...

contour = (F-G).astype(np.float32)
Image.fromarray(contour).save('contour.tif')
```

that gives this:

[image]

Inspection of `contour` shows that the range is `-1` to `16`:

```
print(contour.min(), contour.max())
-1.0 15.869446307662544
```

So, I deduce that your points are probably the ones near zero:

```
points = (contour>-0.1) & (contour<0.1)
```

[image]

So, I can get the list of `X,Y` with:

```
Y, X = np.where(points)
```

Comment: Interesting approach! Many thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, for another slightly *"off-the-wall"* approach, you could save your figure as an SVG to an in-memory `BytesIO` and find the list of line segments in there.